# Is checking ViewBag.Val != null correct in Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

What's the proper way to check in Razor if ViewBag has a value set? I know that [I can do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935828/viewbag-check-to-see-if-item-exists-and-write-out-html-and-value-error)

```
if(ViewBag.Foo != null) {
  ...
}
```

But looking in the events stream in VS 2015 I notice this generates a (handled) `RuntimeBinderException`.

The fact that this throws an error leads me to suspect that this is not the correct way to check the presence of a value, and is actually harming performance (though I have not done any testing). In addition it doesn't help you distinguish between a value being absent and the value being set to `null`.

Is there a more correct approach?

Comment: This is not razor-specific, it's just a dynamic member. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998954/dynamic-how-to-test-if-a-property-is-available, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956648/how-do-i-check-if-a-property-exists-on-a-dynamic-anonymous-type-in-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839598/how-to-detect-if-a-property-exists-on-an-expandoobject, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899613/dynamic-object-how-to-tell-if-a-property-is-defined

Comment: That's a good point @CodeCaster - kinda surprised at the awkwardness of all those approaches

Answer (score -1):

There is no way defined by razor developers, however you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640927/checking-to-see-if-viewbag-has-a-property-or-not-to-conditionally-inject-javasc) to do it by yourself using extension method.

Comment: Well nothing about that **requires** an extension method -  its all just c# and will actually **not work** as an extension method since you can't extend a dynamic. I appreciate the find of the link though.

Comment: The post I shared states what you said in your comment and the accepted answer in the post addresses 'dynamic' nature issue.